# Change Root Site Collection SPOnline

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, root

I have a SharePoint Online instance, in which the root site is set in the old Classic Teams site template. I know that MS has plans to allows to update the template at the end of the year, but I am thinking that I need to just start fresh. As the old root site is still heavily used.

I would like to build a new "root" site, while my company still uses the old one. Then once I have finished and verified that the new "root" site will provided the needed functionality, have mytenant.sharepoint.com point to the freshly built, new, site collection. I see some other posts for SP2013 on Prim, where you would delete the root site and wait an hour or two and then build a new site from there, but not sure that applies to SPOnline, and the loss of "up" time is unacceptable, including that I would have to then build the site without my company being able to use the old one anymore.

Thanks for any help or advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to be possible. What you can do is create another site, design it as required, then migrate the content using a 3rd party tool such as Sharegate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Wish there were just simple way to shift the sites around. gha!